# Why is that the velocity and displacement will go increase after converting from acceleration?

Tags: python

I tried to convert acceleration into velocity and displacement.

But I found that velocity and displacement will increase over time after converted by using cumtrapz.

Where did I go wrong? Or Is there a better way to convert acceleration into velocity and displacement?

Here are my sample code with python:

```
import scipy.integrate as it
acceleration = [1,2,-1,-2,1,2,-1,-2,1,2,-1,-2,1,2,-1,-2,1,2,-1,-2,1,2,-1,-2]
time = range(0,len(acceleration))
velocity = it.cumtrapz(time,acceleration,initial=0)
displacement = it.cumtrapz(time,velocity,initial=0)
fig,ax = plt.subplots(ncols=1,nrows=3,figsize=(16,6),dpi=80)
ax[0].plot(time,acceleration,'-',color='green')
ax[1].plot(time,velocity,'-',color='blue')
ax[2].plot(time,displacement,'-',color='red')
```

[image]

Comment: which package is `cumtrapz` from? what is `it`?

Comment: I think you have the first two parameters to `cumtrapz()` reversed.

Comment: You need to set an appropriate constant of integration. If your data is discreet measurements, I'd recommend doing a sanity check with `np.cumsum((accel - accel.mean()) * np.diff(time, append=2 * time[-1] - time[-2] ))`.

Comment: Sorry, I miss one code. `it` is scipy.integrate

Comment: @jasonharper Do you mean `velocity = it.cumtrapz(acceleration,time,initial=0)`? I tried but the displacement still get increased.